# .bashrc file syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bashrc, syntax-highlighting

I have been using the following lines in my bashrc file for quite some time now and suddenly now I have an error. Here are the lines:

```
make()
{
        /usr/bin/make "$@" 2>&1 | sed -E -e "s/error/ $(echo -e "\\033[31m" ERROR "\\033[0m"/g)"   -e "s/warning/ $(echo -e "\\033[0;33m" WARNING "\\033[0m"/g)"
        return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
}
```

Here is the error:

```
bash: /home/username/.bashrc: line 175: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/username/.bashrc: line 175: `make()'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have an alias for `make` somewhere earlier in the files that
bash reads on startup. Try `alias -p` to list them, and adding `unalias make` in front of the function.

Comment: I had this problem because I had an alias in my bashrc that I later needed to expand to a function. The only way I could get it to register as a function was `function fn() {` instead of `fn() {`. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with your `make` function. When I paste your code into my .bashrc, it works fine.

Think about any recent .bashrc changes you made, they may be the culprit.

One thing that could help locating the problem is the `-x` option.

**Add `set -x` at the top of your .bashrc, then source it again if needed.** When the problem comes up again, the shell will now give you much more useful context regarding the error.

Answer (score 3):

**To restore the ~/.bashrc file:**

```
$ cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.velho
$ cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
$ source .bashrc
```